# Cómo pasar una variable a otra en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy guardando en la función store datos, y luego debo redirigirme al index, donde debo mostrar un dato u otro dependiendo de lo que haya guardado la función store
en este caso es `templateType`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $templateType = $this->templateService->storeSite($request);

    return redirect()->route('template.index', $templateType);
}
```

necesito enviar $templateType a `index` pero sin cambiar la ruta (en lo posible) ya que si hago que la ruta reciba parámetros para empezar tendría los siguientes conflictos

1. La ruta show terminaría siendo la misma que index si recibe parámetros
2. Ingresar a la ruta a través de index sin poner nada en la barra de direcciones

Si hubiera alguna manera de enviar el valor a index sin cambiar las rutas sería mejor, donde a la vez pueda definirle un valor **solamente en caso de que no exista un parámetro de entrada**

algo así

```
public function index($templateType = TemplateType::PLACE)
{
    $PAGE_SIZE = 21;
    $sites = $this->templateRepository->getSites($PAGE_SIZE, null, TemplateType::PLACE, 'asc');
    $sitesGroup = $this->templateRepository->getSites($PAGE_SIZE, null, TemplateType::GROUP, 'asc');
    return view('templates.places.index', compact('sites', 'sitesGroup', 'templateType'));
}
```

en caso de que $templateType entre sin valor, que el valor sea Place (como en el ejemplo), hasta el momento, en el código que tengo así tal cual, la ruta termina siendo

[http://mi-proyecto.test/template?VALORDELPARÁMETRO](http://mi-proyecto.test/template?VALORDELPAR%C3%81METRO)

necesitaría que el index pueda captar ese valor que aparece después del signo de pregunta en la ruta

Answer (score 1):

He utilizado [Sesiones de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data) para hacerlo utilizando el request, así puedo definir valores en caso de que sea nulo y no tengo errores en rutas :)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $templateType = $this->templateService->storeSite($request);
    Session(['templateType' => $templateType]);

    return redirect()->route('template.index')
        ->with(["message" => __('template.generatemplate.create.success')]);
}
```

y para recuperarlo es así

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $PAGE_SIZE = 21;
    $templateType = $request->session()->get('templateType');
    $request->session()->forget('templateType');

    if ($templateType == null) $templateType = TemplateType::PLACE;

    $sites = $this->templateRepository->getSites($PAGE_SIZE, null, TemplateType::PLACE, 'asc');
    $sitesGroup = $this->templateRepository->getSites($PAGE_SIZE, null, TemplateType::GROUP, 'asc');
    return view('templates.places.index', compact('sites', 'sitesGroup', 'templateType'));
}
```

utilizo también el método `forget` luego de guardar el valor porque se queda el valor guardado en toda la sesión, y se supone que en caso de que no haya un valor debe mostrarme otro resultado, y eventualmente me mostrará el último guardado en la sesión, que podría no ser el deseado (en mi caso)